# How to check if an app is running in iOS device from a mac terminal

Tags: ios, console, device

I am trying to launch ios app from python script/terminal using ios-deploy. This is a test app so it might crash and need to relaunch multiple times.
I want to check if this app is currently running or not on the connected device, for my relaunch logic to work. But I am kind of stuck here.
I know idevicesyslog which can capture logs and then parsing logs I can check if my app is currently running or not. But isn't there any sophisticated way to just check if an app is currently running or not in device. Xcode/instruments can get the list of processes via GUI in connected device but I want a command line utility so that I can take certain action.

Answer (score 0):

You can check app or debug app using safari.

Open safari.

And If develop option not available on top navigation bar then open preferences of safari and in advance tab tick show develop option in below that screen.

Comment: Thanks Nikunj, but this would also involve manual intervention. I need a method that can be include in a python/bash script.